# How to use/integrate Discord OAuth2 Callback URL's with Python & HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, oauth-2.0, discord

I am making a Discord OAuth2 Application commission, and my client has asked that I implement my product into their webpage -- windscarft.com/escarya/home.html and that I put the authorisation link where it says Connect to Discord. For this, I need a callback URL that the user is redirected to via the authlink and the callback URL needs to send a request back to my Python script with the given code from the users web address. `(https://localhost:5000/auth/callback&code=?12345678910)`. How am I meant to do this, my current script (below) uses a Flask application and the guild.join functions to make the user join the guild, which is all working fine, but I need the integration part done, as I am no web developer. Code is here, all secret details kept out:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import json
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


BOT_TOKEN = 'insert bot token'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'insert client secret'
CLIENT_ID = 'insert client id'
REDIRECT_URI = 'insert redirect uri'
GUILD_ID1 = 'insert guild 1 id'
GUILD_ID2 = 'insert guild 2 id'


def add_user_to_server(token: str, user_id: str, server_id: str, access_token: str) -> bool:
    url = f'https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/{server_id}/members/{user_id}'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'
    }

    data = {
        "access_token": access_token
    }

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f'User {user_id} added to server with ID {server_id}')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'Error adding user {user_id} to server with ID {server_id}')
        return False



# The callback URL for OAuth2 authorization
@app.route('/auth/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    data = {
        'client_id': REDIRECT_URI,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
        'scope': 'identify guilds.join'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()
    access_token = response['access_token']

    # Get the user ID from the access token
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/users/@me'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    user_id = response['id']

    # Add the user to the server
    invite_code = GUILD_ID1
    invite_code2 = GUILD_ID2
    bot_token = BOT_TOKEN
    add_user_to_server(bot_token, user_id, invite_code, access_token)
    add_user_to_server(bot_token, user_id, invite_code2, access_token)

    return f'Authorised with Discord, adding user {user_id} to server {invite_code}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```